# Is this a placeholder link?

Tags: html, css

On [this page](http://playground.deaxon.com/css/slideshow/), how are the `<img>` references accomplished in the markup? The style sheet has `[src]` selectors, but I'm lost (or stupidly uninformed).

How is the CSS letting the HTML know where the image is?

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Slideshow</title>
<link href=s.css rel=stylesheet>
<ul>
  <li><img src=1>
  <li><img src=2>
  <li><img src=3>
  <li><img src=4>
</ul>
```

```
@-webkit-keyframes f {
       0% { opacity:0; }
      12% { opacity:1; -webkit-transform:scale(1.03) }
      25% { opacity:1; -webkit-transform:scale(1.06) }
      37% { opacity:0; -webkit-transform:scale(1.30) }
     100% { opacity:0; } }

@-moz-keyframes f {
       0% { opacity:0; }
      12% { opacity:1; -moz-transform:scale(1.03) }
      25% { opacity:1; -moz-transform:scale(1.06) }
      37% { opacity:0; -moz-transform:scale(1.30) }
     100% { opacity:0; } }

     body { background:#f0f0eb }
ul, [src] { position:absolute }
       ul { overflow:hidden;
            top:50%;
            left:50%;
            width:650px;
            height:300px;
            margin:-200px 0 0 -340px;
            padding:0;
            list-style:none;
            border:15px solid #fff;
            -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
            box-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2) }

    [src] { opacity:0;
            -webkit-animation:f 12s linear infinite; -moz-animation:f 12s linear infinite }
[src="2"] { -webkit-animation-delay:3s; -moz-animation-delay:3s }
[src="3"] { -webkit-animation-delay:6s; -moz-animation-delay:6s }
[src="4"] { -webkit-animation-delay:9s; -moz-animation-delay:9s }
```

Comment: That's not what's happening - the image src are right there in the markup. What exactly are you asking? `[src]` just selects anything with a `src` attribute (the images). `[src="2"]` selects whichever element has `src="2"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite simply really - they're actually valid URLs, e.g.

```
<img src=4>
```

Is a relative link, pointing to:

```
http://playground.deaxon.com/css/slideshow/4
```

Or:

[image: a]

The "common style" of how the HTML might be formed is:

```
<ul>
  <li><img src="1"></li>
  <li><img src="2"></li>
  <li><img src="3"></li>
  <li><img src="4"></li>
</ul>
```

Not:

```
<ul>
  <li><img src=1>
  <li><img src=2>
  <li><img src=3>
  <li><img src=4>
</ul>
```

I think it's the lack of `"` marks that's confusing you.

Although, as [@Wesley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/398242/wesley-murch) points out, this is also perfectly valid HTML (save for the missing `alt` tags).

Comment: Both of those HTML snippets are valid. `li` doesn't need to be explicitly closed and attributes don't need to be quoted.

Comment: I was just about to show you: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fplayground.deaxon.com%2Fcss%2Fslideshow%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0 Only error is the missing `alt` attributes on the images.

Comment: @Wesley Murch: So essentially you were wrong - both are invalid because of the missing `alt` attributes :P (I jest, I know that doesn't relate to anything)

Comment: @BoltClock I _think_ I managed to sneak that edit into my answer just before your comment... hehe :p

Comment: @Danny Beckett: Yes... yes you did.

Comment: I'm still missing this. Where in the markup is the url the links are pointing to? I can see in the bottom of the viewport that the links go somewhere, but how do you get that into the markup? How do you just get a number in there that is clickable and takes you to the image?

Comment: The image is simply named `4` (for example). It resides in the same directory as the HTML file. Stop thinking like it's a rocket science and come back down to basics; then you'll get it! To put it another way, create a file called `whatever.html` and put in it: `<img src=x>`. Then save a JPG file as `x`. Your image will display. It's just a normal image. Let us know if you're still struggling, and maybe someone else can try to explain it a bit better than me...

Comment: did it. Image doesn't display. I know I'm way overthinking this.<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<img src=x>
</body>

Comment: @pat I just tried it using your exact code, and a random JPG that I renamed to `x` (*not* `x.jpg`), placed in the same dir... it worked :S ...Sadly, I can't upload the files because I don't have hosting at the minute... and I can't give you a JSFiddle because I can't upload the image there.

Comment: @pat Actually, I remembered, I have a public SVN repo. Here's the files: https://www.assembla.com/code/danny-beckett/subversion/nodes/Short%20image%20URLs And here's the web page: https://www.assembla.com/code/danny-beckett/subversion/node/blob/Short%20image%20URLs/test.html

Comment: I got it to work. Is this just really sloppy coding? Isn't the .jpeg extension needed? My ftp client put it on for me, I had to manually take it off.    http://phogan.netai.net/test.html

Comment: @pat Personally, I'd consider it sloppy. Each to their own, it's valid HTML at least...